# Creating a pipe in c between two programs

Tags: c, pipe, fork

I have been working on creating a pipe in c between two programs, reader.c and writer.c. I haven't been able to get the input for the pipe program to work. The pipe program is supposed to take in a int, send it to the writer program, which then pipes its output into the reader program for the final output. Below is the code for the three classes. I think I am close but can anyone help me get the initial int input argv[2] into the writer class then into the reader class?

pipe program (communicat.c)

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{   
    int fd[2];
    pid_t   childpid;
    int result;

    if (argc != 2) 
    {
            printf("usage: communicate count\n");
            return -1;
    }
    pipe(fd);

    childpid = fork();

    if (childpid == -1)
    {
         printf("Error in fork; program terminated\n");
         return -1;
    }

    if(childpid == 0)
    {
            close(1);
            dup(fd[1]);
            execlp("writer", "writer", fd[1],(char *) NULL);  
    }
    else
    {
           childpid = fork();
    }
    if( childpid == 0)
    {
           close(0);
           dup(fd[0]);
           close(fd[0]);
           close(fd[1]);
           execlp("reader", "reader", (char *) NULL); 
    }
    else
    {
          close(fd[0]);
          close(fd[1]);
          int status;
          wait(&status);
    }
    return(0);
}
```

Reader.c

```
int main()
{
   int count; /* number of characters in the line */
   int c; /* input read */
   count = 0; 
   while ((c = getchar())!= EOF) 
   {
        putchar(c); count++;
        if (count == LINELENGTH) 
        {
              putchar('\n'); count = 0;
        }
   }
   if (count > 0) 
        putchar('\n');
    return 0;
}
```

Writer.c

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
     int count; /* number of repetitions */
     int i; /* loop control variable */

    if (argc != 2) 
    {
         printf("usage: writer count\n");
         return -1;
    }
    else count = atoi(argv[1]);

    for (i = 0; i < count; i++) 
    {
        printf("Hello");
        printf("hello");
    }
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Why don't you close the pipe's files before executing writer the same way you do for reader?

Comment: Also reader and writer can't access to argc and argv of calling program, what they receive depends on your `exec()` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct the code to exec writer this way:

```
if(childpid == 0)
{
    close(1);
    dup(fd[1]);
    close(fd[0]);
    close(fd[1]);
    execlp("writer", "writer", argv[1], (char *) NULL);  
}
```

Comment: Thank you, closing the fd in the writer made it work. I knew it was something small like that.